# Print two strings with new lines into the table

Tags: bash, printf, echo, columnsorting

I have two strings that I wish to print in to table.

```
string1="HEADER1\ndata1\ndata2"
string2="HEADER2\ndata3\ndata4"
```

How can I get this output in bash:

```
HEADER1   HEADER2
data1     data3
data2     data4
```

I try:

```
echo "$string1  $string2"
```

but I get totally mess.. Is there some command to print strings in columns..?

Comment: Your strings don't contain newline characters (line feed), but '\n'. Whether or not the \n is translated into a newline character, depends on the command which you use on the string. Your `echo` does not do such a translation.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this:

```
paste <(echo "$string1") <(echo "$string2") | column -t
```

Comment: I get this error: `syntax error near unexpected token (`

Comment: It should work fine, although using echo -e might be better to interpret the \n  characters.

Comment: @SashaMilic Then you're not using bash.

Comment: code works for me (even without `column`) when I use `echo -e ...` like this `paste <(echo -e "$string1") <(echo -e "$string2")`. Tested on `Bash 5.1.16` on `Linux Mint 21`

Answer (score 0):

You use csv or some other delimiter a bit more easily.

```
string1="HEADER1,data1,data2"

h1=$(echo "${string1}" | cut -d',' -f1)
d1=$(echo "${string1}" | cut -d',' -f2)
d2=$(echo "${string1}" | cut -d',' -f3)

cat << EOF >> file
"${h1}"

"${d1}"
"${d2}"
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to an array and loop over it like this:

```
string1="HEADER1\ndata1\ndata2"
string2="HEADER2\ndata3\ndata4"

arr=( $(printf "$string1 $string2") )

for ((i=0,j=3; i<3; i++,j++)); {
    printf "${arr[$i]}\t${arr[$j]}\n"
}
```

Result:

```
HEADER1 HEADER2
data1   data3
data2   data4
```